# Automation process based on count roll-up summary field

Tags: process-builder, custom-field, roll-up-summary

I have an automation process based on the returned value from a count roll-up summary field.

For instace I have two statuses.

1. `Primary status`
2. `Secondary status`

Let's say the user creates two records. 
One record with `Primary status` and another record with `Secondary status`.

The count which rollup field will return will be 2, because the number of records is two: One with `Primary` and one with `Secondary`.

At a certain point in time the user checks a custom checkbox field.

As soon as the checkbox is checked I need to know how to make the rollup field to start couting only the records with Secondary status.

Istead of having 2 the returned count will have to be reduced the to 1, becuse there is only one record with `Secondary status` and also because the custom checkbox field is checked.

Another example:

User creates
1. record with `Primary status`
2. record with `Primary status`
3. record with `Secondary status`
4. record with `Secondary status`
5. record with `Secondary status`

As soon as the user checks the custom checkbox field the returned count will have to be equal to 3, because there are three records with `Secondary status` and also because the custom checkbox is checked.

Until the custom checkbox field remains checked only the records with `Secondary status` must be counted.

Please advise how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two roll-up summary fields: `Count_of_All_Status__c` and `Count_of_Secondary_Status__c`. Both fields should be hidden (not shown on the page layout).

Then you need to cover them with a formula field to determine which is shown, based on the checkbox field:

```
IF(My_Checkbox_Field__c, Count_of_Secondary_Status__c, Count_of_All_Status__c)
```

You can't change the definitions of the rollups themselves based upon the checkbox, but you can manipulate how the data is presented.